# Ramaze app won't load due to Rack version conflicts

Tags: ruby, ramaze

When I run `ramaze start` I get this.

```
C:/mowes/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1990:in `raise_
if_conflicts': Unable to activate innate-2012.03, because rack-1.5.2 conflicts w
ith rack (~> 1.4.1) (Gem::LoadError)
```

Here's my gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'ramaze', "<= 2012.04.14" #old version
gem "innate", ">= 2012.03", "< 2012.11" #old version
gem 'sequel'
if defined? ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'production' then gem 'pg' else gem 'sqlite3' end
gem "sentry-raven", :git => "https://github.com/coderanger/raven-ruby.git"
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
gem 'rdiscount' 
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'pony'
gem 'bacon'
gem 'koala'

#source 'http://mirror1.prod.rhcloud.com/mirror/ruby/'
#gem 'nokogiri'
#gem 'capybara'
```

I'm using an outdated version of Ramaze and `gem list` says `rack (1.5.2, 1.4.1)`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing rack 1.5.2 should solve it.